# JAVA + ORACLE: precision issue in performing substraction

Tags: java, oracle, precision

I have the following issue.

After I extracted two values from the database, I performed a subtraction obtaining a precision issue.

For example, the two values extracted are:

```
Double a1 = rs.getDouble("A");  ---> 20.4
Double a2 = rs.getDouble("B");  ---> 15.4
```

and the subtraction returns

```
Double diff = a2 - a1;  ---> 4.999999999999998
```

My expected result was 5.0 obviously.
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Please, could you provide the link of the question?

Comment: The link should be at the top of the question

Comment: @JonK Sorry, I didn't see it. Thanks